# how to implement Splitview in cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I am iphone developer but now i am implementing cocoa application.I am new for this cocoa application.I want learn cocoa development application.I want to learn step by step all controllers.First i want to learn splitview controller.Please help me for this .Please provide me some related document or sample example for this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSplitView` documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

There is sample code provided on that page